# SQL Server 2012 Money Data Type Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqldatatypes

I am using this formula

```
(p.Price - i.Price) * q.Qty
```

in SQL Server 2012. There are `p.Price` values of 0 or `null`. The data type for the `p.Price` and `i.Price` is `money`, the `q.Qty` is `int`.

So, if the calculation is `(0-10.00) * 50 = -500.00` (it's a negative number because it is product that are bought on a schedule) but I always get 0 or null as a result in my data table.

Update :

```
 (sum(p.Price - i.Price) * q.Qty)
```

but I am getting an invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate or the group by clause ?

Comment: Price doesn;t normally end up in negative numbers

Comment: You need some grouping or sum(q.qty)

Comment: NUll + anythign = null same with all math operations

Comment: Put `q.QTY` inside the sum expression: `sum((p.Price - i.Price) * q.Qty)`

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server [`money`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms179882.aspx) type can be negative. It has this range:

```
-922,337,203,685,477.5808 to 922,337,203,685,477.5807
```

Check your data and formula, it should be working as expected:

```
DECLARE @m1 money = 0;
DECLARE @m2 money = 10;
DECLARE @qty int = 50;

SELECT (@m1 - @m2) * @qty
```

**Result**

```
(No column name)
-500.00
```

If the values can be NULL, you can use `ISNULL` to turn them into zeros:

```
DECLARE @m1 money = NULL;
DECLARE @m2 money = 10;
DECLARE @qty int = 50;

SELECT (ISNULL(@m1,0) - ISNULL(@m2, 0)) * ISNULL(@qty, 0)
```

**Result**

```
(No column name)
-500.00
```